# How do I run a v8 engine standalone and debug with Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8, node-inspector, embedded-v8

I built a v8 binary for my platform (MacOS).

I could start a v8 shell by executing that binary and run arbitrary JS code.

```
bash-$ ./v8
v8> var foo = 42
v8> 42
```

What I want is to somehow use chrome devtools as the debugging front-end for this v8 instance, like how I can use devtools for remote-debugging another chrome instance.

To put simply, something like this

```
bash-$ ./v8 --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Answer (score 3):

Since NodeJS already has good support for Chrome DevTools, I forked NodeJS and tweaked it to run my code in vanilla V8 environment.

Build my fork: https://github.com/joelewis/node

Then run the binary:

```
$ /out/Debug/node --inspect --inspect-brk mycode.js
```

This will open Chrome DevTools window with a breakpoint in the first line of mycode.js. In this environment there's no NodeJS globals (like require, exports, module). It's a pure V8 environment!